# Simple Form Validation using Nuxt 3 Composition API

Tags: javascript, nuxt3

I have a Nuxt 2 mixin which looks like this:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    errors: {}
  }),
  methods: {
    clearErrors () {
      this.errors = {}
    },
    error (attribute) {
      return this.$_.get(this.errors, attribute, null)
    },
    setErrors (response) {
      this.clearErrors()
      const errors = this.$_.get(response, 'data.errors', {})
      if (!this.$_.isEmpty(errors)) {
        for (const property in errors) {
          if (errors[property][0]) {
            this.errors[property] = this.$t('phrases.error') + '. ' + errors[property][0]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `errors` data property indicates current form validation errors retrieved from Laravel API. The errors are set usually when the user clicks Submit button.

I want to convert this to Nuxt 3. Here's what I have so far in Nuxt 3:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const user = reactive({
    email: '',
    password: '',
    confirmed: 0,
    blacklisted: 0
})
let { errors } = useValidation()
const { $transformErrors } = useNuxtApp()
async function store() {
    const { data, error } = await useApiFetch('/api/admin/users/store', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: { user },        
    })
    if (error) {
        errors = $transformErrors(error)
    }
}
</script>
```

Looking at the DevTools I see that `errors` property gets set properly, but I don't see the error message in the template:

```
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="input-email" class="form-label">{{ $t('email') }}</label>
  <span class="text-danger ms-1">*</span>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="input-email" aria-describedby="text-email" v-model="user.email">
  <div class="invalid-feedback d-block" v-if="errors.email">
    {{ errors.email }}
  </div>
  <div id="text-email" class="form-text" v-else>We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was able to fix the issue. I was updating `errors` property wrong way - there should be `errors.value = $transformErrors(error)`